# Making one of Liferay communities (called sites) not indexed in solr

Tags: solr, indexing, liferay

We are using Liferay (6.1.20 EE) with Solr search engine.

Now Solr indexes everything. Can we somehow set up Solr (or Liferay) to prevent one Site from being indexed?

It means all articles documents present on that Site would not be indexed and would not be present in Solr.

1) Should this be done with Solr configurations/schema filters before Index starts?
OR
2) Should it be customized in Liferay Indexer classes (with help of Hooks or EXT) to skip content being indexed.

Thanks for your thoughts and suggestions.

Regards,
Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom version of the solr-web WAR file that you need to install to make the Liferay/SOLR integration work. In the WAR file you'll find SolrIndexWriterImpl. This is the place that everything passes through that will be indexed in SOLR. You could create your own custom implementation of this class that uses the information in the SearchContext parameter, that's passed into each method, to decide if something should be indexed or not.

The latest code for solr-web can be found here: http://svn.liferay.com/repos/public/plugins/trunk/webs/solr-web/

Based on this code I was also able to create a solr-web.war that works on the more recent SOLR versions instead of the ancient 1.4.1 version Liferay uses by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That makes sense! We are using Liferay EE, will this Solr-web from public SVN work? Maybe you know from where could we get sources of this plugin compatible with EE version?

Comment: As an EE customer you can download a ZIP containing the sources for this WAR file from the Liferay Customer portal. Just log in, go to Places > Customer Portal, click on Downloads > Portal Plugins and scroll to the solr-web section. The direct link for me is: http://www.liferay.com/group/customer/downloads?p_p_id=3_WAR_osbportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=maximized&_3_WAR_osbportlet_fileName=/plugins/6.1.10/solr-web-src-6.1.10.1-ee-ga1-20120308105411784.zip

Comment: from version 6.1.20 EE, solr-web plugin can be downloaded only from new Liferay place: Marketplace. They didn't have there functionality to download the source. But after contacting the Support we have got sources and I successfully could modify this plugin to inject some filters between Liferay and Solr.<br/>
Thank you, fimez!